# NLU doesnt recognize few names

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-nlu

I am working on a chatbot that uses both Watson conversation and NLU. My chatbot is designed to provide information about other people - friends, colleagues (ex: their current position, contact number etc.,). Chat bot isnt able to recognize few names as persons. How do I handle this situation ? Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

NLU does recognize person pretty good, if you are using Watson Conversation along with NLU, I am not sure how you are combining both of them. Can you explain it a bit more?

I faced a similar situation using NLU, here are the few ways I overcame it
1.NLU relies on context, instead of sending smaller texts, send bigger texts. 
2. It also relies on Grammatical features, usually having correct punctuation, First letter capital names for Person, City Names helped me get better results